# Настройка шрифта Windows terminal

Tags: windows, консоль, шрифты

Как исправить слишком большое расстояние между буквами в терминале Windows[image: Большой интервал выглядит так!].
Поставил Ubuntu-font, выглядит как-то так: G e t - A l i a s.
Подскажите как уменьшить интервал между символами, пожалуйста.

Comment: А зачем ты хочешь в терминале не моноширинный шрифт? Поставь Ubuntu Mono, что ли…

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Алексей! Я не даже и не знал отличие Обычного шрифта от Моно